# Compiling a gimp plugin

Tags: terminal, homebrew, plugins

I wish to compile the Gimp plugin  ["Save for Web"](http://registry.gimp.org/node/33)  on Mac 10.8.4. I use  [brew](http://brew.sh)  for package management but libgimp2-dev is missing. I've downloaded Gimp 2.8.6 from  [here](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html) . I've downloaded the latest source cd into that directory, but when I run `./configure` I get the error of package requirements not being met *(gimp-2.0|gimpui-2.0 needs to be greater than 2.3 / gimp-2.0|gimpui-2.0 not found)*

Comment: did you try not using brew for installation ?

Comment: I searched but didn't find relevant packages. What do you have in mind?

Comment: It appears homebrew isn't going to have gimp in it's repo any time soon: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/8835

Comment: Have you managed so sort it out? There are now native several Gimp versions for OS X. I am using the `brew cask install gimp` and I was interested about the same missing plugin.

Comment: Yes, but not as per my original question. I've forgotten I posted this. Turns out the gimp.lisanet.de maintains a version of gimp that has the "Save for Web" functionality. Thanks to your asking, I see my version is outdated. Check it out: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Developers.html

Comment: I found the source code with some pre-build packages for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/i386/libgimp2.0-dev/2.8.16-1ubuntu1

Can't find any pre-build of this package for OSX, and it bothers me too much when trying to build this package, there a lot of dependencies.